# using startMethodTracing and stopMethodTracing with ddms

Tags: android, performance

I'd like to measure performance in a specific function (and everything it calls).  To do so, it seems I should use Debug.startMethodTracing() and Debug.stopMethodTracing(), then somehow start DDMS tracing.

However, when I open a DDMS view in Eclipse and click the Start Method Profiling button, it starts immediately - not when startMethodTracing() executes.  The result is a huge trace file with mostly irrelevant stuff in it.  Too hard to narrow in (I tried a few times).

Apparently TraceView is deprecated.  Should I hack a way to use that anyway?  Is it any better?  What is the correct approach to do what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Debug.startMethodTracing() and Debug.stopMethodTracing() a .trace file will be created on the device. The exact location of it is printed out in the logcat.

Look for entries  that start with "TRACE STARTED" and "TRACE STOPPED". You then can use adb pull to get the .trace file from your device and open it in the tool of your choice for analysis (e.g. Eclipse or some third party product)

There is no need to manually use DDMS in Eclipse if you're using the above calls. The .trace file itself can simply be opened in Eclipse by using File -> Open

Comment: I found a file dmtrace.trace.  It's in some binary format and I don't see any TRACE STARTED or TRACE STOPPED in it.  However, it does display some trace statistics when I open it in the DDMS window.  It appears that it only contains one sample between start... and stopMethodTracing.  That's better than nothing :)  I there a way to get an aggregate of samples?  (I am trying to measure overhead while scrolling - there's lot's of UI gaps which really clutter up a more encompassing trace sample.)

Comment: If you want to record multiple traces use startMethodTracing(String traceName) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startMethodTracing(java.lang.String)). The .trace file in this case will be named after the parameter you pass in

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I didn't try the traceName variant yet.  Hopefully it will concatenate rather than replace.

Comment: It will create multiple files if you pass in different strings (just have some running number or something like that) but I don't know of any possibility to combine those into one. Afaik you'll have to look at them one by one